# Can i detect when an app changes its PID when it resets, instead of detect when an app closes?

Tags: batch-file

I play a game called assetto corsa..
The developers decided to hit us hard on the development side of things this last update.

long and the short of it. i have to now launch the server through an EXE that resets the acserver.exe after a race has ended so we can rotate tracks..

I had written a small bat file to detect the exe closing and restarting. And it was then suposed to copy over some CFG files to a folder so we had the right cars for the track.. 
Here is that code.

```
@echo off
:start
start Console_AC_TrackCycle.exe
Ping Loopback 
cls

:run1
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq acserver.exe" | find /I "acserver.exe"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO spa1 
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO run1 

:spa1
del /f /q cfg\*.*
copy presets\spa\*.* cfg\
GOTO run2

:run2
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq acserver.exe" | find /I "acserver.exe"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO green1 
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO run2 

:green1
del /f /q cfg\*.*
copy presets\Nordschleife\*.* cfg\
GOTO run3

:run3
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq acserver.exe" | find /I "acserver.exe"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO nur1 
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO run3

:nur1
del /f /q cfg\*.*
copy presets\nurburg\*.* cfg\
GOTO run4

:run4
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq acserver.exe" | find /I "acserver.exe"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO mug1 
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO run4

:mug1
del /f /q cfg\*.*
copy presets\Mugello\*.* cfg\
GOTO run5

:run5
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq acserver.exe" | find /I "acserver.exe"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO sil1 
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO run5

:sil1
del /f /q cfg\*.*
copy presets\Silverstone\*.* cfg\
GOTO run6

:run6
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq acserver.exe" | find /I "acserver.exe"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO imo1
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO run6

:imo1
del /f /q cfg\*.*
copy presets\Imola\*.* cfg\
GOTO run7

:run7
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq acserver.exe" | find /I "acserver.exe"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO vold1 
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO run7

:vold1
del /f /q cfg\*.*
copy presets\voldermort\*.* cfg\
GOTO run8

:run8
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq acserver.exe" | find /I "acserver.exe"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO mag1
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO run8

:mag1
del /f /q cfg\*.*
copy presets\Magione\*.* cfg\
GOTO run9

:run9
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq acserver.exe" | find /I "acserver.exe"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO vall1
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO run9

:vall1
del /f /q cfg\*.*
copy presets\Vallelunga\*.* cfg\
GOTO rung

:rung
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq acserver.exe" | find /I "acserver.exe"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO spa1
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO rung 

Pause
```

Ignore the pause at the end i put that there to check it looped like i expected..

Now the problem is Acserver.exe does not really close. it resets. Its PID changes but the Exe never dissapears..

Is there something i can do to edit the above code so it will do what it is suposed to do when the exe closes, but now do it when the PID changes.

thanx.

Comment: A process cannot change its PID. You cannot do what you want robustly with just a batch file. You need an exe. Create the process and WaitForSingleObject() on the process handle -- when the process dies the handle becomes signalled, so you know for sure it has exited. Presumably, it starts a second instance of itself before exiting. (PIDs can be reused over time .. as soon as a process terminates *and* all handles to it are closed its PID is available to be used by the next process to be created - you cannot predict when this will happen though).

Comment: My bat file was supposed to exchange files every time acserver.exe reset. 
But because it neve leaves the task
The bat file cannot move on to run2 or spa1 
and will always be stuck in a loop of run1..

Acserver.exe either never closes and just changes its PID instead. 
or It closes and reopens so fast nothing realizes it closed, but it did close and reopen because it has a new PID..

Comment: You could `for /f "skip=3 tokens=2" %%I in ('tasklist /fi "imagename eq acserver.exe"') do set "PID=%%I"`to store the PID at the beginning of the script, then in `:run2` do `tasklist | find "%PID%" && (timeout /t 1 >NUL & goto run2) || goto green1` to detect when `%PID%` is no longer in the task list.